# getting status of the employer for an employee on a particular effective date when duration of employment is given using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

| Employee No. | Employer | Date_of_joining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | adobe | 22/03/2004 |
| 123 | amazon | 14/07/2010 |
| 123 | adobe | 04/04/2013 |
| 126 | Ericsson | 09/06/2004 |
| 126 | Google | 30/06/2010 |
| 126 | Amazon | 30/08/2019 |

Based on the above table , I was trying to trying to write a excel formula to  populate the values in the following Table:
shown one example in row 1 for employee 123

| Employee No. | 01/07/2010 | 01/07/2011 | 01/07/2012 | 01/07/2013 | 01/07/2014 | 01/07/2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | adobe | amazon | amazon | adobe | adobe | adobe |
| 126 | - | - | - | - | - | - |

The appproch I was following is as follows:

If seen from excel's point of view, excel would 1st check the employee then check if effective date is less than joining date and then pick the corresponding employer.

Using formula:

**=IF(AND(MATCH($C14,$A$2:$A$7,0)>0,D$13<C2),OFFSET($C2,0,-1),"NA")**

But I know I'm not using the right logic, Humble request to help me on this !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using <kbd>Excel2010</kbd> you need some array formula. Try below-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$7=$A13)*($C$2:$C$7<=B$12),ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$1),""),1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]